# How to break scanner once user enters number less than 0?

Tags: java, arrays, validation, java.util.scanner

#### The Problem

Hey guys, my problem is figuring out how to append integers from a scanner object into an array. The caveat is the scanner should stop taking integer values once the integer is less than 0. In other words, no matter how long the inputted array is, it should stop taking integer values once the scanner detects a negative value. **This question is using the Java language.**

From there, it should print out the inputted array.

Example:

When the input is

> 12 22 22 23 25 -1

it should stop the scanner immediately at -1 and output the following array:

> 12 22 22 23 24 -1

#### What I've Tried

Since the array can't be assigned fixed size for a standard array, I went with an Array List, which will give the freedom to append as many values from the scanner object. Once I figured this step, I did a simple user validation for any entered integers, which is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //  Initiate scanner and a new array
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<Integer> userValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");

   //  While the scanner reads an integer, add integers to the array list
   while (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
      userValues.add(scnr.nextInt());
   }

   //  Print out the array list
   System.out.println(userValues);
 }
```

The input and output for the top will be like this.
INPUT

> 1 2 3 45 32 1 
>   L

OUTPUT

> [1, 2, 3, 45, 32, 1]

This only works for basic integer validation and stops entering a string or other data types into the array. I can't seem to figure out how to stop the scanner object and store the entire array. The following code is my attempt at the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   //  Initiate scanner and new array
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<Integer> userValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   boolean isPositive = true;

   System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");

   //  TODO: Once the user enters a value less than 0, break the loop
  while(scnr.hasNextInt() && isPositive) {
     if(scnr.nextInt() < 0) {
       isPositive = false;
     } else {
       userValues.add(scnr.nextInt());
     }
   }
   System.out.println(userValues);
}
```

At failed attempts, this doesn't work and gives me weird outputs, which I can't wrap my head around.

INPUT

> 1 23 45 -1
>   -1

OUTPUT

> [23, -1]

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify a little bit.

https://ideone.com/GmZ7nH#stdin

```
 Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<Integer> userValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   System.out.print("Enter numbers: ");

   //  TODO: Once the user enters a value less than 0, break the loop
  while(scnr.hasNextInt()) {
     int temp = scnr.nextInt(); 
     if( temp < 0) {
       break;
     } else {
       userValues.add(temp);
     }
   }
   System.out.println(userValues);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense to me and it works for my bigger program, I appreciate this dude!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `nextInt` twice, so it adds the next int and skips over one. Store it in a variable instead.

```
while(scnr.hasNextInt() && isPositive) {
     int next = scnr.nextInt();
     if(next < 0) {
       isPositive = false;
     } else {
       userValues.add(next);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about checking for -ve input at the start of the loop ?

```
    int val;
    while ((val = scnr.nextInt()) >= 0){
        userValues.add(val);
    }

    // Print out the array list
    System.out.println(userValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop a scanner and successfully print the output, you have to basically call an `if` statement and say:

```
if(num < 0){
--your condition---
}
```

Note: I used "num" as an example, the variable has to be a scanner variable in order for the scanner to stop, otherwise if you set a condition with a variable that's not a scanner variable, the scanner wouldn't stop.